# How to make sure at least one CheckBoxPreference is selected

Tags: android, checkboxpreference

I have a `PreferenceActivity` containing a number of `CheckBoxPreference` and I want to make sure that at least one of them is selected, any suggestion on how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up registering the same instance of `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` on all my `CheckBoxPreference`. The listener keeps a set with my `CheckBoxPreference` and reacts when the user unchecks one, returning false if it's the only one checked.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use .setChecked(true) on the checkbox control

i.e.

// get the control
final CheckBox chkRemember = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

// pull th evalue from your preferences
strChecked = rwPref.readWriteUserSetting(DevDroidSLX.this, "Read", "CheckboxValueA" , "" );

```
      if ( strChecked.equalsIgnoreCase("True"))
      {
          chkRemember.setChecked(true);
      }
      else
      {
          chkRemember.setChecked(false);
      }
```

Comment: Simplified as chkRemember.setChecked(strChecked.equalsIgnoreCase("True"));